# How to make a bootable USB disk for installing Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, lenovo-laptop

with my new Lenovo E145 I am stuck when it comes to installing a fresh Windows 7/ dual boot device.

The laptop has no CD/DVD drive, and had Windows 7 pre-installed. I downloaded an ISO image X17... and put this image on the USB stick. The stick boots fine, but after pressing "Install Windows" - I end up in an endless loop about missing drivers on the stick.

In the BIOS, I've tried to set the SATA driver to "compatibility" mode already, and everything else to "Legacy" - but no luck. The installation boot ends up asking about drivers.

Researching more, I found some hints on using the Windows Deployment Kit. But it is here, where it gets fuzzy for me. The process refers to making an ISO file with drivers out of the initial Windows 7 CD - which I don't have.

How can I make a bootable USB stick?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: if you have iso file then use win2bootic software for making bootable usb stick.

Comment: what about the drivers? The main problem here is about Windows asking for drivers

Comment: which drivers it is asking, usb or anything else

Comment: see the added screenshot - note that I am using the USB stick, while it asks for CD/DVD drivers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1 :

When Windows is asking for driver, just click Cancel. You will be brought back to the welcome screen. At the welcome screen, remove your USB drive, insert it back to DIFFERENT USB PORT. Click Install Now again. The installation process will be like usual.

This problem happened to all new version of updated Windows 7 installer. I think, it is due to failure of Windows installer to remain its detection to the USB drive. It lost the connection, and became confused, don't know where to find the USB drive it used to read before.

When we re-insert the USB drive, Windows installer will detect the USB drive back, and continue like usual.

### Method 2 :

If above solution doesn't work
then download the [sata driver from here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds019446) and put in same bootable usb, Press ok in screen, browse and install.

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it working. The Lenovo has 3 USB ports, and the last USB port that I tried could read the stick. BTW for Method 2, I think you need to make a WIM file, which sounded complicated (unpacking/packing the ISO file). A bit of elaboration how to do this might be nice for others.

Comment: @poseid I simply use win2flash or win2bootic software for making pendrive bootable and after making bootable pendrive just copy sata driver exe file in pendrive when it asks for driver just browse and load that exe file. it will work.

Comment: Another possibility -- just try a different usb port from the outset. ;)

Comment: Specifically, use the single USB 2.0 port. Not one of the USB3 port which has no drivers on the win7 installation iso.

Comment: This only works because of what @Hennes says on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

***It's very simple, let's make it***

1st Thing 1st - Download the proper copy of Windows 7 or whatever the os you need as a ISO Image

2nd- To make Windows USB use [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) or [Windows 7 USB](http://wudt.codeplex.com/)

Windows 7 Professional x64 (64-bit)

English: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65805/X15-65805.iso
German: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65813/X15-65813.iso
French: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65811/X15-65811.iso
Spanish: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65843/X15-65843.iso

Windows 7 Professional x86 (32-bit)

English: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65804/X15-65804.iso
German: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65812/X15-65812.iso
French: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65810/X15-65810.iso
Spanish: http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65842/X15-65842.iso

Comment: thanks for the links - they might be helpful for others too!

Comment: @poseid for the full list see http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make a bootable USB stick?

You already created one. There is no problem here. YOu can boot from the USB pendrive (and you are doing this using the firmware (EFI, BIOS) drives for USB.

However after this initial bootstrap windows takes over. Specifically windows 7 takes over. Windows 7 ships with drivers which will recognise most USB2 ports, but it does not ship with USB3 drivers.

Looking at your laptops specs you have the following connectors:
**1 USB 2.0**, 2 USB 3.0 / 3.1 Gen1, 1 VGA, 1 HDMI, 1 Kensington Lock, Audio Connections: audio combo, Card Reader: SD, SDHC, SDXC, MMC

That means you either:

1. Install from the USB2 port, or
2. You add USB3 drivers to the windows 7 install disc, or
3. You need inert media with the correct USB3 drivers somewhere where windows can find then (e.g. ona DVD, or on a USB pendrive connected to the USB2 port).

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into BIOs and reset everything to default
2. Google the chipset model of your motherboard and download the drivers
   2.1 Extract the drivers onto a USB thumb drive (it can be same one you booted from, place into its own seperate folder)
3. Boot and get to the screen as your example above, click browse and navigate to the folder on the thumb drive in which you extracted the drivers to

Once you provide the drivers, Windows will be able to see the hard drive.